# Git Ignore: Ignore .es5 and .min files

Tags: git

I start use [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) to transform and minify my .js files but i don't want that the generated files be tracked on git.

[image]

I tried add the following code on git ignore, but it is not working:

```
**/*es5.js
**/*es5.min.js
```

Can any one tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you already committed those files you can't ignore them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are already being tracked by git, they cannot be ignored unless you tell git to stop tracking them.

Run the following

```
git rm -r --cached **/*es5.js **/*es5.min.js
git commit -m"Untrack generated files"
```

Additionally you can change your `.gitignore` file to read;

```
*es5.js
*es5.min.js
```

.gitignore already recursively looks through the repository for filenames